# Why is my Flink streaming job on AWS EMR running on local mini cluster?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, apache-flink, amazon-emr

I'm quite new to Flink and Kafka and I wrote a simple flink streaming job to test out Flink on EMR. The Scala code looks like this

```scala
object KafkaStreamingJob {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val senv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val bootstrapServers = ... // Kafka bootstrap servers
    val properties = new Properties
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers)
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-group")
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")

    val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("test", new SimpleStringSchema, properties)
    val kafkaDataStream = senv.addSource(consumer).print

    senv.execute("Demo Flink App")
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```xml
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
...
```

Then I submitted the job to EMR with the suggested argument `flink-yarn-session -n 2 -d`, but for some reason my job is always started on "local embedded Flink mini cluster"

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment (main): Running job on local embedded Flink mini cluster
```

and the error log says:

```
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="kill -9 %p"
#   Executing /bin/sh -c "kill -9 6282"...
```

I think the OOM error might have something to do with the fact I'm running job on "mini cluster". But I couldn't find anything related to not running "mini cluster" in AWS documentations. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on how you submit the job?

Comment: Furthermore, what Flink version are you using?

Comment: Did you set up the EMR cluster with Flink?